# How to stretch a fixed div to screen when positioned inside a fixed container?

Tags: css, screen, stretch, html

I have a 100x100px container, centered in the middle of a page. I got a nested div inside, which is 100px tall, that I wanna stretch to the width of my screen.

How can I do this?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: A fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net will help understanding your issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s7nhw/1/ something like this?

Comment: @reinder This seems to be the right answer. Thx! I have made it a bit more easy read here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7nhw/12/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@reinder gave me the right answer:

```
<html>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nested-div"></div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nested-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7nhw/12/.